# Autocomplete html tags in jsx (sublime text)

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimetext, reactjs

I would like to be able to use autocomplete for html tags in my react/jsx code. The same way it works for html files. Can i configure sublime text 3 to enable tags autocomplete for jsx files?

Comment: Have you tried any of the JSX or Babel plugins to see if they meet your needs?

Comment: Yes i'm using babel-sublime, it does a good job, but unfortunatly html autocompletion is not working.

Comment: I don't believe it's a feature.

Comment: so is it just a set of snippents?

Comment: Yes, and maybe some formatting control.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Worth noting that you can enable Sublime's built-in tag closer in JSX by copying and slightly modifying the keybinding for `/` that comes with `Default.sublime-package`. Add the following to your custom keymap:

```
{ "keys": ["/"], "command": "close_tag", "args": { "insert_slash": true }, "context":
  [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "(text.html, text.xml, meta.jsx.js) - string - comment", "match_all": true },
    { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": ".*<$", "match_all": true },
    { "key": "setting.auto_close_tags" }
  ]
}
```

Assuming you're using the Babel package, the selector `meta.jsx.js` will match JSX syntax and enable the tag-closing behavior. The scope name may be different for other packages, in which case you can use [ScopeHunter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeHunter) to inspect the scopes that are applied by your preferred JSX syntax.

Comment: This works great, and actually addresses the OP's question best. He didn't ask: how can I use emmet in JSX. He asked, how can I make sublime handle jsx the way it handles html. 

One caveat: you probably want to put this in `Default.sublime-keymap` in your User folder rather than change the base one.

Comment: @btwebste You do realize SublimeText heavily relies on plugins to extend itself? While this answer works for the limited scope of the question, emmet is a great tool to have in your tool belt. Don't get me wrong, I don't question the greatness of this answer (has my upvote), but other answers are equally good (especially since one gets what the OP asked for and then some).

Comment: I was going to comment that someone should make a plugin for this. So I did: https://github.com/FMCorz/AutoCloseTags. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This does not seem to work in Sublime Text 4?

Comment: @SherylHohman I've reported the issue with ST4 here: https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/5309

Answer (score 35):

Install:
babel & Emmet

Then add this into your Key Bindings - User

"Key Bindings - User" is on "Preferences > Key Bindings"

```
{
    "keys": ["tab"], "command": "expand_abbreviation_by_tab", "context": [
        {
            "operand": "source.js", 
            "operator": "equal", 
            "match_all": true, 
            "key": "selector"
        },
        {   
            "key": "selection_empty", 
            "operator": "equal", 
            "operand": true,
            "match_all": true 
        }
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "next_field", "context":
    [
        { "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
}
```

Comment: To edit "Key Bindings - User" is on "Preferences > Key Bindings", then the right one.

Comment: This one worked for me, whereas the selected answer did not. Thanks!

Comment: Your config closes tag before tag is typed in full. Tag is `View`. I type `Vi`, then `[Tab]`, then I get `<Vi><Vi>` and not `<View><View>`. This is definitely wrong behavior.

Comment: Green - the problem with HTML5 is any string of characters in a doc could be a <tag></tag> but the very nature of custom tags.

Comment: Simple answer!!! please add @choco Li comment in your answer.

Answer (score 26):

It will not autoclose the brackets for you as you type, but you can just use Sublime's built-in tag closer with **<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>** for mac, or **<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>** for windows.

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me in my testing. Can someone confirm this actually works for them in Sublime? Does it perhaps rely on a plugin.

Comment: @XMLilley works for me. The only React-specific plugin I have is https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime. Perhaps that makes a difference, since it's what provides syntax highlighting for JSX files.

Comment: It comes from this line in the keybindings config: `{ "keys": ["super+alt+."], "command": "close_tag" },`

Answer (score 8):

I heavily suggest the combination of [babel-sublime](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime) and [emmet](http://emmet.io/). If you specify "JavaScript (Babel)" as your syntax, both packages will work together, with emmet properly generating "className" and "htmlFor" if needed.

The only downside is that the expand will not work with TAB but with CTRL+E. This is due to TAB having a bunch of other usage in JavaScript.

Comment: I have both of these packages installed but do not have "JavaScript (Babel)" available to me as an option inside the _Syntax_ menu. The _JavaScript _ option has a popover menu but here only _JavaScript_ and _JSON_ are listed. Any insight into this?

Comment: @IsenrichO On my machine, it's listed under (Babel) -> JavaScript (Babel).

Comment: I actually find `Ctrl-E` *very* convenient - easy to type, easy to remember.  And I'm happy `tab` is *not* used !  "className" excellent - I thought I'd have to try and write that one myself.  :-) Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @IsenrichO You should find it at Syntax "Babel > Javascript(Babel)"

Comment: @ChocoLee Good call. I was being dumb.

Answer (score 7):

Based on Daniel's answer, I made a plugin just for this.

Source: https://github.com/FMCorz/AutoCloseTags

To install:

1. Add the above repository with `Package Control: Add repository`
2. Execute the command `Package Control: Install package`
3. Select `AutoCloseTags`

Comment: perfect answer.

Comment: Great package however, can you please update so that the close enables when you've type the last bracket of the opening tag. Like so... <div

then, upon typing >

Sublime will then immediately print

<div></div>

Answer (score 4):

As others suggested: install **[Babel](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel)** and **[Emmet](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet)** !

**[Emmet Abbreviation's list](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/)**
( see the [demo here](https://docs.emmet.io/actions/expand-abbreviation/) )  ( and [**cheat sheet** here](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/)  )
You  don't even need to type in the angled brackets -> Emmet -> Settings will do that, the closing tag, and more!

**update**: Emmet (v2+) now works with the **tab** key for **JSX** and **HTML** elements when you start them with `<` .
For example `<div` then `tab` will auto complete to `<div></div>`
While `<MyComponent` then `tab` will expand to `<MyComponent></MyComponent>`

This new feature, is enabled by default. To turn it off, open the Emmet settings and change the jsx_prefix setting to false: `"jsx_prefix": false`
To do that open Preferences -> Package Settings -> Emmet.

---

Previous version of Emmet:

Use **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>** to expand the abbreviation.

Emmet docs: great at explaining the abbreviations.. *But Failed to state* how to "Expand Abbreviation" - *at least, I was unable to locate it*.

From Sublime, I

- opened up:  `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Emmet -> Key Bindings - Default`
- searched for `expand_abbreviation`
- found `ctrl+e`

Happiness - Works like a Charm :-)

---

**update: I no longer recommend AutoCloseTags.

At least in my installation of Sublime Text 4, it no longer seems to work.**

**Use Babel plus Emmet instead.**

I *also* recommend installing **[AutoCloseTags](https://github.com/FMCorz/AutoCloseTags)**, as provided by [FMcorz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47206554/5411817) and [Daniel Shannon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41094347/5411817).

This combination gives

- auto-closing of (interpreted tag due to nesting rules), by simply typing `</`, great on the fly,  whereas, Emmet will
- expand an "abbreviation" to full opening and closing tags (and more) by pressing `Crtl-E`.  This is great for creating a skeleton.

Answer (score 2):

If you have babel installed for sublime, try open your .js and .jsx files and go to view > syntax > open all with current .. > babel > javascript (babel) to view correct syntax highlighting and use CTRL + E to auto-complete html tag inside ur .jsx

Comment: Is it your problem?

Comment: This is useful, as many people forgot to change their Syntax to 'Babel->JavaScript' before trying above solutions.